# Error reading detecting sdcard partitions

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, sd-card, corruption

The output of `lsblk` is the following

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0  59.6G  0 disk           -- this is the device I want to mount
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    50G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 179.5G  0 part /home
```

running `dmesg` I get this:

```
[  201.444695] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  201.444704] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  201.497792] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.551413] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.604686] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.657946] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.711121] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.764454] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.764707] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  201.764716] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  201.764739] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[  201.818036] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.871394] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.924724] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  201.977765] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.031381] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.084368] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.084515] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  202.084520] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  202.137849] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.191373] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.244477] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.298054] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.351392] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.404724] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.404992] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  202.405003] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  202.457833] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.511144] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.564705] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.618055] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.671398] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.724734] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.724958] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  202.724969] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[  202.724997]  mmcblk0: unable to read partition table
[  202.781381] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.834705] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.888055] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.941390] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  202.994476] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.048050] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.048313] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 125042560 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  203.101386] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.154721] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.208054] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.261149] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.314406] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.368064] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[  203.368322] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 125042560 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  203.368333] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 15630320, async page read
```

How can I recover from this error?

Comment: Any solutions? I have the same problem with a 64GB Samsung SD card and the reader on a Dell E7250. The only workaround so far has been to use the SD card with a different SD card reader. It seems like some incompatibility between specific cards and readers. It would be great to know if there is a software solution.